# ActiveSupport::Concern code placed inside the included block or in the module body

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, activesupport-concern

Suppose I have the following namespace with a `Base` module that defines some methods that can be reused

```
module MyNameSpace
  module Magic
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    class_methods do 
      def magic_field(field_name)
        # Defines methods and attributes based on field name
      end
    end
  end
end
```

What is the difference (if there is any) between

```
module MyNameSpace
  module Foo
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern
    include Magic

    included do
      magic_field(:foo)
    end
  end
end
```

and

```
module MyNameSpace
  module Foo
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    included do
      include Magic
      magic_field(:foo)
    end
  end
end
```

(The question is about the difference of `include Magic` being either outside or inside the `included` block)

Comment: I dont understand the down vote, is a valid question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the concern is included in a class, the `include` and `class_methods` allows for the receiving class to inherit those methods.

`included` adds instance methods while `class_methods` adds class methods.

Source: [Rails Concerns Docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html)

On the other hand, if your question is the difference between the placement of `include Magic`, there is no difference in how the class would function.

Comment: Yes my question was about the `ìnclude Magic`either outside or inside the `included` block

Comment: _When you define more than one included block, it raises an exception_. When using `load` in the rails console, it won't override methods added via the same _Concern_ `included` block, due to [this error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52459894/4352306):  _Cannot define multiple 'included' blocks for a Concern_. So we may say there's an actual difference, because in a _**hot swap**_ `included` block won't be redefined.