# Dokku: remote App container failed to start

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-5, dokku, amazon-lightsail

I have an application build with Rails 5.0.0. I can deploy the application normaly to Heroku, without erros. I configurated an Lightsail with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and I instaled dokku. The applicaiton already run on another amazon server (EC2 with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS), but the process of deploy on there it's weird, thats why I changing it to another server with dokku. When I run git push dokku, the process starts, but at the end of it I get the error bellow.

```
CHECKS file not found in container: Running simple container check...
-----> Waiting for 10 seconds ...
d09da8aad3ecbd6b62b189bd74b3d35c9d1b11c4a4a06e6a063687b7e4ae60fb
remote: App container failed to start!!
=====> 99aulas web container output:
       => Booting Puma
       => Rails 5.0.7.2 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:5000
       => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
       /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/concern.rb:126:in `included': Cannot define multiple 'included' blocks for a Concern (ActiveSupport::Concern::MultipleIncludedBlocks)
        from /app/app/models/models/concerns/productable.rb:5:in `<module:Productable>'
        from /app/app/models/models/concerns/productable.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
```

But this code already run on another two servers without the same error. In the file that is mentioned on the log I have the code bellow:

**model Productable**

```
extend ActiveSupport::Concern

included do

    extend FriendlyId
    include PgSearch

    before_validation :update_slug, on: :update, prepend: true

    acts_as_paranoid

    has_one :highlight, as: :highlightable, dependent: :destroy

    scope :published, -> { joins(:teacher).where(status: PublishStatus::PUBLIC) }
    scope :draft, -> { where(status: PublishStatus::DRAFT) }
    scope :from_category_group, -> category_group { joins(category: :category_group).where("category_groups.slug = ?", category_group) }
    scope :from_category, -> category { joins(:category).where("categories.slug = ?", category) }
    scope :from_teacher, -> teacher_id { where(teacher_id: teacher_id) }        
    scope :highlighted, -> { joins(:highlight) } 

    pg_search_scope :search, 
        associated_against: {
            category_group: :name,
            category: :name,
            teacher: :name
        }, 
        against: [:title, :description, :keywords],
        ignoring: :accents,
        using: {
            tsearch: { prefix: true }
        }

end

def update_slug
    #force update slug only if title changed
    self.slug = nil if self.title_changed?          
end
```

end

Someone knows whats it can be?

Thanks!!

Comment: Hi have you tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24244519/cannot-define-multiple-included-blocks-for-a-concern-activesupportconcern

Answer (score 0):

I've been reading this question of yours and the issues in the attached comment and it's pretty puzzling. After doing some of the reading I'm wondering if this has something to do with `bootsnap`. If you're running `bootsnap` could you try running your rails container without it? I saw some evidence that seemed to point towards people with `bootsnap` fixing this issue by toggling `load_path_cache` and/or `autoload_paths_cache`.

See: https://github.com/Shopify/bootsnap/issues/75