# Cannot define multiple 'included' blocks for a Concern (ActiveSupport::Concern::MultipleIncludedBlocks) minitest error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, minitest

While running the minitests, I am getting this error ..

> Cannot define multiple 'included' blocks for a Concern
> (ActiveSupport::Concern::MultipleIncludedBlocks)

This is the command I am using

```
RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec ruby test/api/functional/f1/file_1.rb


Rails -v gives Rails 4.2.11.3
Ruby -v gives ruby 2.4.7p357 (2019-08-28 revision 67796) [x86_64-darwin19]
rvm -v gives rvm 1.29.9


require_relative '../../test_helper'
# require Rails.root.join('test', 'core', 'helpers', 'controller_test_helper.rb')
# require Rails.root.join('test', 'core', 'helpers', 'users_test_helper.rb')
Dir.glob("#{Rails.root}/test/core/helpers/*_helper.rb") { |file| require file }

class ABC::EFG < ActionController::TestCase
  # tests Freshrelease::SettingsController

  include FreshreleaseConfig
  include UsersTestHelper
  include ControllerTestHelper

  def setup
    super
    before_all
  end
```

Please help.
P.S it was successfully running before

Comment: You need to show the content of your file ..

Comment: @maxpleaner added in the question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24244519/cannot-define-multiple-included-blocks-for-a-concern-activesupportconcern

Comment: If you look at the stack trace it will surely tell you which one of the three included modules are to blame. We can't actually do anything but guess with the provided information. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QhiJNAsMBdE